# How can I merge multiple rows by specific ID without to lose my other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one Pandas Dataframe who looks like this:

```
articleID  name    categorieId
1          test       1
1          test       2
1          test       3
1          test       4
2          pencile    1
2          pencile    2
2          pencile    3
```

And my question is how can I merge by the categorieId and still have my other columns "articleID" and "name"?
I want a result like this:

```
articleID  name     categorieID
1          test     [1, 2, 3, 4]
2          pencile  [1, 2, 3]
```

If I merge this with this command:

```
df = df2.groupby("articleID")["categorieID"].apply(list).rest_index(name="categorieID")
```

I get a result like this:

```
articleID   categorieID
    1       [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    2       [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

As you can see the name is missing and it mulitples the categorieIDs by the factor 2 (I dont know why).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this suffice?

Your data `df`:

```
   articleID     name  categorieId
0          1     test            1
1          1     test            2
2          1     test            3
3          1     test            4
4          2  pencile            1
5          2  pencile            2
6          2  pencile            3
```

Use `DataFrameGroupBy.agg`, with `tolist()` on your categorieId column.  Then `reset_index()`

```
res = (df.groupby(['articleID']).agg({'categorieId': lambda x: x.tolist(),'name':'first'})).reset_index()

print(res)

   articleID   categorieId     name
0          1  [1, 2, 3, 4]     test
1          2     [1, 2, 3]  pencil
```

You can of course rearrange the columns afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I found the issue why it multipled the categorieIds... I have some bad data into my dataset. 
But thanks for the solution! :)